# how to migrate bag file containing roslib/Log and visualization_msgs/MarkerArray

Tags: ros, rosbag, markerarray, ros-electric, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I want to migrate a bag file containing recorded with Diamondback to Electric.
The bag contains roslib/Log messages which seem to be missing in Electric, plus visualization_msgs/MarkerArray for which there are no migration rules.

So I run rosbag fix xxx.bag xxx-fixed.bag and after a while I am confronted with the message:

```
* From: roslib/Log [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb]
   To:   Unknown
    1 rules missing:
     * From: roslib/Log [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb]
       To:   Unknown
 * From: visualization_msgs/MarkerArray [f10fe193d6fac1bf68fad5d31da421a7]
   To:   visualization_msgs/MarkerArray [90da67007c26525f655c1c269094e39f]
    1 rules missing:
     * From: visualization_msgs/Marker [bc7602ad2ba78f4cbe1c23250683bdc0]
       To:   visualization_msgs/Marker [18326976df9d29249efc939e00342cde]
Try running 'rosbag check' to create the necessary rule files or run 'rosbag fix' with the '--force' option.
```

So I do as it wishes and run rosbag check  2011-06-24-19-30-36.bag -g myRule.bmr which results in:

```
WARNING: Within rule [GENERATED.update_visualization_msgs_MarkerArray_f10fe193d6fac1bf68fad5d31da421a7] cannot migrate from subtype [Marker] to [Marker]..
The following migrations need to occur:
 * From: roslib/Log [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb]
   To:   Unknown
    1 rules missing:
     * From: roslib/Log [acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb]
       To:   Unknown
 * From: visualization_msgs/MarkerArray [f10fe193d6fac1bf68fad5d31da421a7]
   To:   visualization_msgs/MarkerArray [90da67007c26525f655c1c269094e39f]
    1 rules missing:
     * From: visualization_msgs/Marker [bc7602ad2ba78f4cbe1c23250683bdc0]
       To:   visualization_msgs/Marker [18326976df9d29249efc939e00342cde]
The message type roslib/Log appears to have moved.  Please enter the type to migrate it to.
>
```

What am I supposed to do now? And does anyone have a migration rule for the MarkerArrays or know how to auto-generate them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28143/how-to-migrate-bag-file-containing-roslib/log-and-visualization_msgs/markerarray/) by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 290 on 2012-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roslib/Log migrations to rosgraph_msgs/Log

I don't know how to migrate the Marker.  It may be the case that auto-rule generator just works on it.  (Make sure to backup your data before you give it a go)

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1